# How to reduce the size of notify-send in vscode during laravel-mix

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-mix

Is there anyway to reduce the size of the notify-send dialogbox in vscode when using laravelmix. It takes too much space and sometimes makes it difficult to code as the notify-send screen takes a lot of space in vscode,

Thanks in advance

[image: LaravelMix notification in vscode]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all mix notifications in your `webpack.mix.js` with:

```js
mix.disableNotifications();
```

If you want to disable just the success notifications you can do so by:

```js
mix.disableSuccessNotifications();
```